# Image above a shape in plotly

Tags: r, image, layout, plotly, shapes

I want the elements of my plotly graph to be displayed in this order: grid < shape < image.

If I add layer='below' to my shape, it goes under the grid.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode='markers') %>%
  layout(shapes = list(type = 'line', x0 = 0, x1 = 1, y0 = 0, y1 = 1),
         images = list(source = 'https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/r-logo.png?raw=true"',
                       x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
                       sizex=0.5, sizey=0.5,
                       xanchor = 'center', yanchor = "middle",
                       layer = 'above'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think to make this work is to use `htmlwidgets`.

```
plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode='markers') %>%
  layout(shapes = list(type = 'line', x0 = 0, x1 = 1, y0 = 0, y1 = 1),
         images = list(source = 'https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/r-logo.png?raw=true',
                       x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
                       sizex=0.5, sizey=0.5,
                       xref = "x", yref = "y",
                       xanchor = 'center', yanchor = "middle")) %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el){
                        m = document.querySelector('g.layer-above');
                        m.appendChild(m.firstElementChild);
                        }")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kat!

I still have 2 issues:
1. When I download the plot, I still have the logo under the line
2. When I display two plotly in the same Shiny page, the shapes go back over the images again (if I only display one plotly, it's ok):

Comment: About the two plot issue... change `m = document.querySelector('g.layer-above');` to `m = el.querySelector('g.layer-above');` in the JS. (I made this mistake in your answer and one other about the same time!) How are you downloading the plot?

Comment: Thank you, all good for the second issue!

I download the plot via the Plotly toolbar.